# "Expected response code 220 but got an empty response" ao enviar email laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando enviar um email utilizando o laravel.

Tentei algo como:

**api.php:**

```
Route::get('emailAnimalEncontrado', function () {
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'Novo animal encontrado em Franca. Você pode ajudá-lo?'
    );

    Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message){
        $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'Novo animal encontrado em francaa.');
        $message->to('renatoveronese600@gmail.com')->subject('teste email laravel');
    });
    return response()->json('Email enviado com sucesso', 201);
});
```

meu arquivo .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=renatoveronese600@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=SENHAEMAIL
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**Em resources/views/email.blade.php:**

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>

    OI MUNDO

</body>
</html>
```

**Em mail.php:**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
  'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'renatim@hotmail.com.br'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Renato Veronese'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('renatoveronese600@gmail.com'),

    'password' => env('SENHAEMAIL'),

 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: `env('renatoveronese600@gmail.com')`??

Comment: Alterei para MAIL_USERNAME, continua o mesmo problema.

Comment: Também tem um `env('SENHAEMAIL')` perdido ali. Altere e rode o `php artisan config:cache`.

Answer (score 1):

O GMail tem algumas seguranças que podem estar a afetar o teu código, de formas que não são tão claras como deviam. Faz assim: no teu ficheiro .env, muda o valor da variável MAIL_ENCRYPTION para tls, ao invés de a teres a null.

À priori, tudo deve começar a funcionar corretamente. No entanto, se continuares com o mesmo problema, segundo este artigo https://artisansweb.net/sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-laravel/, deves ir à tua conta GMail e ativares a opção para permitires o acesso de aplicações menos seguras.